# Multi-config Support - How to set application ID?

Tags: ar.drone

Does anyone know the method / commands to send, to enable and use multi-config support so I can store application specific data?

The SDK 2.0 Developer Guide mentions the `AT*CONFIG_IDS` command, but I'm not able to make it work. I'm trying the sample commands below:

```
// set the application ID
AT*CONFIG=12,"CUSTOM:application_id","2902050D"

// clear config ack
AT*CTRL=13,5,0

// set application description, using new app id
AT*CONFIG_IDS=14,"00000000","00000000","2902050D"
AT*CONFIG=15,"CUSTOM:application_desc","My SDK Test"

// clear config ack
AT*CTRL=16,5,0

// re-read config data
AT*CTRL=17,4,0
AT*CTRL=18,5,0
```

But in the returned config, nothing has changed:

```
custom:application_id = 00000000
custom:application_desc = Default application configuration
```

I've also tried prefixing the first `CUSTOM:application_id` config command with an `CONFIG_IDS` command but with no avail:

```
// set the application ID
AT*CONFIG_IDS=11,"00000000","00000000","00000000"
AT*CONFIG=12,"CUSTOM:application_id","2902050D"
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, it seems that all configuration names should be all lower case; despite the category being upper cased in the Developer Guide examples.

Therefore the following works fine:

```
AT*CONFIG=12,"custom:application_id","2902050D"
AT*CTRL=13,5,0

AT*CONFIG_IDS=14,"00000000","00000000","2902050D"
AT*CONFIG=15,"custom:application_desc","My SDK Test"

AT*CTRL=16,5,0
AT*CTRL=17,4,0
AT*CTRL=18,5,0
```